# typedef struct with pointer and constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I am writing a `struct _Point3d` and typedefed it to `Point3d` and provided a pointer declaration `PPoint3d` next to `Point3d` (Please see code). There is a constructor which initializes members of the `struct`. I have twofold queries here.

```
typedef struct _Point3d
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    _Point3d(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {

    }

}Point3d, *PPoint3d;
```

**One:**
What does this convention of providing pointer after struct name (typedef) really means? provided we can create the pointer of `Point3d` like this

```
Point3d* _ppoint2 = new Point3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

**Two:**
Is there any difference in creating instances of `Point3d` in these two different ways.

```
PPoint3d _ppoint1 = new Point3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
Point3d* _ppoint2 = new Point3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: `Point3d` is a `struct _Point3d` and `PPoint3d` is a `struct _Point3d*` or in other word a pointer to `struct _Point3d` or a pointer to `Point3d`. Second question, no it's the same thing.

Comment: 1) The typedefing of the pointer here is in my opinion the work of cranks that don't like the language syntax. 2) There is no difference. 3) Names in global namespace beginning with an underscore are reserved.

Comment: Why is this tagged C when you are using `new`?  If this is just for C++ then the declaration does not follow the C++ convention for declaring and using classes.

Comment: actually I dont see the point of using a typedef here at all. imho it is much simpler and more clear to write `struct Point3d { float x,y,z;}` there is no need for a typedef

Comment: You write a lot of C code before, right ? So, forget everything and learn C++ like a new language

Comment: Related: [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: That funky typedef is a Microsoft-ism; it's their convention for defining C types for the Windows API. It's not needed in C++, and it mostly just looks silly.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Point3d`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am writing a struct _Point3d and typedefed it to Point3d and provided a pointer declaration *PPoint3d next to Point3d

Stop right there, Kiddo. This is 2016, not 1997. No need to follow arcane microsoft practice any more.

Do this instead:

```
struct Point3d
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    Point3d(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
    {

    }
};

using PPoint3d = std::unique_ptr<Point3d>;
using SharedPoint3d = std::shared_ptr<Point3d>;
```

Raw pointers are to be used in low-level implementations. When used as part of an interface they make your code susceptible to being silently hijacked by your user's unintended and un-noticed mistakes.

For this reason they are evil when used as part of an interface. So evil that it is evil to even hint to users of your class that they should use them.

Comment: Can we get off the train of "raw pointers are *so* evil". There is nothing wrong with non-owning raw pointers.

Comment: @StoryTeller The reason for the existence of `std::experimental:: observer_ptr` is precisely because raw pointers are evil, especially when used as observers, simply because a user can hijack them by mistake.

Comment: `observer_ptr` will not prevent undisciplined users from doing something bad. It's just ridiculous to assume the language feature is evil in itself.

Comment: @StoryTeller you're right. The language feature itself is necessary and 'not evil', but the use of it as part of an interface certainly is. I'll update the answer.

Comment: everything is evil when you misuse them. The appearance of newer paradigms doesn't make older ones evil

Comment: Agree with @Richard Hodges, and consider the scenario of legacy application written in C (no C++), could I avoid raw pointers then?

Comment: @A.B. I assume you mean when using the C features from the C++ programs? I would encourage you to wrap the C pointers in C++ smart pointers at the earliest opportunity. The custom deleter of the smart pointers makes this possible in every scenario.

Comment: Roger That! and what is the purpose of *PPoint3d in the line "} Point3d, *PPoint3d;" I have seen this conventions alot in Win32 API.

Comment: @A.B. The win32 API was written in C a long time ago, and the MFC was written before people knew better (and indeed before c++ was mature). Microsoft's APIs are not a model of the future, more a warning about the past ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First, you are in C++, so you don't need to `typedef` your structs. You can write this.

```
struct Point3d {
//...
};
```

The typedef idiom is the norm in C, but not in C++ (and since you use `new` you clearly are in C++, not in C).

Secondly, there is no difference, as a typedef really is a type alias.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences, but effectively the same thing is happening.

In

```
 Point3d* _ppoint2 = new Point3d(....);
```

You are taking the address of the new Point3d and storing it in the L-value (left hand side) called _ppoint2.  You are doing the same with

```
 PPoint3d _ppoint1 = new Point3d(....);
```

The only difference is how you are writing the L-value.

_ppoint2 is a struct type, but you are annotating it with an asterisk to make it a pointer type.  With _ppoint1 you have "baked in" the pointer to the struct.

Functionally they are identical except in type.  This difference in type means that the manner in which you use them will differ, because that manner must be type-aware.  For example, one does not need to include the asterisk to get the pointer value from _ppoint1.